# How to Redirect http to https in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, http, https

I want the site to be redirected to https when I request the site with http and always be redirected to https

Comment: Something like [In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](https://serverfault.com/q/67316/362305), through server side configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, redirecting http to https is done at the server configuration level. For a quick and dirty redirect, you can use a `.htaccess` file.

**Quick and dirty: .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**The right way on apache:**
[Redirect on apache](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/)